# Как изменить приоритет выполнения get запроса. Не работает callback.Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Всем доброго дня! Прошу помощи. 
Возникла необъяснимая для меня проблема. Коротко объяснить не получиться. Отрываясь от контекста, суть следующая: строки кода, где я вызываю get запрос, выполняются webApp приложением раньше, чем те строки кода, которые были вызваны до вызова get запроса. Не помогает так же и конструкция с callback.

А теперь код. ФУНКЦИЯ  sync_data() вызывается с двумя параметрами. 1 - диапазон ячеек и 2 - название функция для callback.

```
// СИНХРОНИЗАЦИЯ ИЗ РЕДАКТОРА
// переносит данные из редактора в реестр

function sync_data(active_range,callback){
  try{   
    var A1Notation = active_range.getA1Notation(); // A1Notation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()    
    var data = active_range.getValues(); // данные которые надо перенести   
    }
  catch(e){
    Browser.msgBox("Произошла ошибка. Код 101");
    return;
  }
  // ЗАПИСЬ ДАННЫХ В РЕЕСТР
  try{ 
    var ss_id = "***"; // id таблицы реестра
    var name_sheet = "main_data"; // имя листа, куда писать данные    
    var sheet_reestr  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id).getSheetByName(name_sheet); // 
    sheet_reestr.getRange(A1Notation).setValues(data); 
  }
  catch(e){
    Browser.msgBox("Произошла ошибка. Код 102");
    return;
  }


   //owser.msgBox("Данные в реестр записаны");



// ВЫЗОВ ГЕТ ЗАПРОСА. ФУНКЦИЯ ДАЛЕЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ОТ АКК IT  
  callback(A1Notation);
  //get_request(A1Notation); // вызов ГЕТ запроса для доступа к редакторам
}
```

В качестве callback выступает функция get_request()

```
function get_request(A1N) {       
  var urlWebApp = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec"; // url lib_reg_form webApp
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlWebApp + "?A1N=" + A1N); // get запрос к lib_reg_form webApp. В библиотеке запускается функция load_data()
}
```

Функции в WebApp следующие 
doGet():

```
function doGet(e) { 
   load_data(e.parameter.A1N,call_back); // вызов функции загрузить данные с реестра 
}
```

load_data():

```
function load_data(A1N,callback) {


  var id_red;
  var ss_id_reestr = "***"; // id таблицы реестра
  var name_sheet = "main_data"; // имя листа реестра
  // Получить данные из диапазона ячеек и записать их в переменную data
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id_reestr).getSheetByName(name_sheet).getRange(A1N).getValues();
  callback(A1N,data);
}

function call_back(A1N,data){
  // запись данных в другие таблицы из реестра
  var  id_red;
  id_red = "***";
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_red).getSheetByName("Редактор").getRange(A1N).setValues(data);

  id_red = "***";
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_red).getSheetByName("Редактор").getRange(A1N).setValues(data);

}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы строки в функции sync_data() выполнились до того, как будут выполняться строки функций WebApp. Функция sync_data() записывает данные в таблицу 1. А WebApp из таблицы 1 должна эти данные переписать в другие таблицы.

Но как бы я ни пытался, всегда WebApp выполняется раньше. В итоге в другие таблицы из таблицы 1 пишется всегда старое значение, а потом только в таблицу 1 записывается новое. Ровно наоборот.

Если не вызывать get запрос, а просто сразу сделать копирование, то работает нормально. Но такой методо мне не подходит.

```
function sync_data(active_range,callback){
  try{   
    var A1Notation = active_range.getA1Notation(); // A1Notation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()    
    var data = active_range.getValues(); // данные которые надо перенести   
    }
  catch(e){
    Browser.msgBox("Произошла ошибка. Код 101");
    return;
  }
  // ЗАПИСЬ ДАННЫХ В РЕЕСТР
  try{ 
    var ss_id = "***"; // id таблицы реестра
    var name_sheet = "main_data"; // имя листа, куда писать данные    
    var sheet_reestr  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id).getSheetByName(name_sheet); // 
    sheet_reestr.getRange(A1Notation).setValues(data); 
  }
  catch(e){
    Browser.msgBox("Произошла ошибка. Код 102");
    return;
  }

 // получить данные из реестра
  data =  sheet_reestr.getRange(A1Notation).getValues();
  //записать в другую таблицу эти данные
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getRange(a1Notation).setValues(data); 
}
```

Comment: Вам нужна отладка. Это не тот форум, где кто-то за вас будет что-то отлаживать. Я вижу, что у вас doGet ничего не возращает, а следовательно смысл этого пируэта теряется. Возможно, если вы приведете обычное описание того, что должна делать программа, это можно будет решить.

Comment: Спасибо. Я нашел решение проблемы. Это использование метода SpreadsheetApp.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, что обещания(Promises) [не работают в JS google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561735/are-there-promises-on-google-apps-script).

Есть нюанс выполнения методов API гугл таблиц. Они собираются в кучу и выполняются за раз. 
Читайте описание в документации [подробнее](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush). 
Если происходит вызов функций api  гугл табл,а в конце get запрос, тогда get запрос выполнится первым. 
Чтобы избежать это, необходимо использовать метод [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush). Он принудительно выполняет все операции с таблицей до строки где он вызван.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Лист1");
  var data = ss1.getRange(1, 1).getValue();

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id_").getSheetByName("Лист1");
  ss2.getRange(1, 1).setValue(data);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var urlWebApp = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID/exec"; // url lib_reg_form webApp
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlWebApp); //  
}
```